# C# Bank Account Deposit

Tags: c#, winforms, account, bank

Hi guys I have this bank account project which displays account info when user selected index. This information includes the current balance that the account has. And then I also has deposit simulation which the amount I deposit should add up to the current balance. I cant figure out why its not doing the work.

I have this code for my selectedindex which pulls up the account info.

```
private void accountNumComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (accountNumComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {


            ownerIdLabel.Text = "0001";
            balanceLabel.Text = savings1.Balance.ToString("c");
            interestLabel.Text = (string.Format("{0}%", savings1.Interest));
            interestRLabel.Text = "Interest Rate:";
        }
```

And I have this code for the deposit button

```
    private void depositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal amount;
        if (decimal.TryParse(depositTextBox.Text, out amount))
        {
            account.Deposit(amount);
            account.Balance += amount;
            depositTextBox.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pls enter valid amount.");
        }
    }
```

The amount I enter wont add up to the current balance in the balancelabel.Text . Thank you so much for your help.

EDIT: I also got this in my BankAccount class

```
public decimal Balance
    {
        get { return _balance; }
        set { _balance = value; }
    }
    public BankAccount(decimal intialBalance, string ownerId, string accountNumber)
    {

        _balance = intialBalance;
        _customerId = ownerId;
        _accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }


    public void Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        if ( amount>0)
        _balance += amount;
        else
            throw new Exception("Credit must be > zero");
    }
    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        _balance -= amount;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `savings1` and `account` are two separate instances of `BankAccount` class which you are operating on. I don't see any updated on `savings1` instance. Elaborate on how you are populating/refreshing `savings1` instance.

Comment: Also you are doing a double deposit. Once in `Deposite` method and then setting `account.Balance` again in `depositButton_Click`. I pray that wont be done in final code. :)

Comment: Oh I got the savings1 instance here, 

 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<SavingsAccount> savings = new List<SavingsAccount>();
        SavingsAccount savings1 = new SavingsAccount("0001", "31-1000", 100m, 0.01);

Comment: Does SavingsAccount inherit BankAccount? It must as in real-world.

Comment: Hi. Clearly you are not reflecting the changes by updating your label.

You're lacking balanceLabel.Text = account.Balance.ToString("c"); after your depositText.Clear() function. Refer to my post below.

Comment: Oh Ophitect sorry I forgot to reply to your comment. I did what you told me but its just changing the value instead of adding it up :(

Comment: Define what you mean by adding it up. Also, wouldn't changing the value be updating the balance?

Comment: Because I got the initial balance right? so when I selected a value from the combobox it will display all the account information including the current balance that account has right now. Like in this case, when I selected the firs value in the combobox, the account currently has $100.00 on account. so if i want to deposit $50.00 i want the balance to update to $150.00 but when I try to do the update label like you told me, the label changes to $50.00 instead of adding 50 to make it 150.00

Comment: This mean your account.Balance is 0 before deposit. How are you linking account to the saving? It would be good if you show us the initializing of variable code.

Comment: Ohhh I see.. maybe I should declare a parameter in here ya? 

 private BankAccount account = new BankAccount();

Comment: I tried putting a number inside the paramter of this method  private BankAccount account = new BankAccount(1000); and it does the work. But how can I do it with the initial balance in the parameter to replace that 1000 in there?

Comment: Yep. You could actually make a method to update the ui based on the private variable account. And the combo box will actually update the private variable account. Refer to my editted post. It is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deposit button event handler doesn't have the code to change your balance label.

```
private void depositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal amount;
    if (decimal.TryParse(depositTextBox.Text, out amount))
    {
        account.Deposit(amount);
        account.Balance += amount;
        depositTextBox.Clear();
        balanceLabel.Text = account.Balance.ToString("c"); // This line added
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pls enter valid amount.");
    }
}
```

Edited:

Using your code

```
private BankAccount account;
private void accountNumComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (accountNumComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
           account = (BankAccount) savings1;
    }
    updateUi();
}

private void updateUi() {
    ownerIdLabel.Text = "0001";
    balanceLabel.Text = account.Balance.ToString("c");
    interestLabel.Text = (string.Format("{0}%", account.Interest));
    interestRLabel.Text = "Interest Rate:";
}

private void depositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal amount;
    if (decimal.TryParse(depositTextBox.Text, out amount))
    {
        account.Deposit(amount);
        account.Balance += amount;
        depositTextBox.Clear();
        balanceLabel.Text = account.Balance.ToString("c"); // This line added
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pls enter valid amount.");
    }
}
```

Note: The above edit is based on the code that you give. You might have to modify a little bit to fit your goal. Also, take note that you actually hardcode the ownerId text.

Answer (score -1):

In your Deposit routine you are changing the balance:

```
_balance += amount;
```

However, in your depositButton_Click routine you are also changing the balance:

```
account.Deposit(amount);
account.Balance += amount;
```

You don't need to amend the balance here because deposit will already do it.

Comment: Question is why deposit is not reflecting new value, and not why it is doubling.